# GWT unit test for Activity and View

Tags: unit-testing, gwt, junit

Does anybody have a link for a tutorial on how to write JRE junit tests (extending TestCase and not GWTTestCase) that tests Activity and Views in GWT 2.1?

Best regards

Pich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to test views, which of course contains reference to the objects that calls GWT.create(), using PowerMock.

For Activities it is easy todo using Mockito for instance to mock the View.

Answer (score 2):

Views can only be unit tested using GWTTestCase because they call (either explicitly or implicitly) `GWT.create()`.

To test Activities use mock Views to avoid use of `GWT.create()`.

Comment: what if activity contains reference to the objects such as GWT PlaceController which calls GWT.create() under the hood? (unfortunately PlaceController is a class so it cannot be mocked easily...)

Comment: `Place Controller` has a constructor specifically for this: `PlaceController(EventBus eventBus, PlaceController.Delegate delegate)` In this case you'll mock the `Delegate` instead of the `PlaceController`. It's worth noting, as well, that most mock frameworks (i.e. EasyMock) support mocking concrete classes (with limitations).

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I prefer to mock only interfaces, so that's why I had this issue.